# How has George Soros been so successful in investing?

Tags: investing, hedge-funds

What is George Soros's skill set?

It seems he has an innate understanding of human behavior!

It is shocking how successful he has been, especially since he is not a value investor (Buffet) or math genius (Thorp) or criminal (Cohen).

Comment: Is this really so opinion-based as to be unanswerable? I think a well-defended answer is possible, citing Soros' writings.

Answer (score 5):

If you’re interested in Soros, his books are all worth a read. He is a strange and alchemic mix of analysis, philosophy, gut feel/biological feedback and student of history.

Arguably his fundamental skill has been his insights and bets around [reflexivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexivity_(social_theory)) and its consequences on markets. He was also one of the earlier financial stars to embrace [Popper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Popper) and the broad implications of empirical falsification.

In overly simplistic and arguable terms: what Buffet has been to the underlying fundamentals of companies, Soros has been to the fundamentals of crowds, individuals and governments.